# Trying to move Org A Project A work items to Org B Project B

Tags: azure-devops, devops, migrate, azure-devops-migration-tools

I just want to move an entire project of work items from one "org" to the other. When I run the migration.exe with the below config, I'm receiving an error. I did watch the YouTube video and try to follow the instructions in git but I'm unable to figure out what I've done wrong. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

[image]

```
{
  "Version": "9.1",
  "TelemetryEnableTrace": false,
  "workaroundForQuerySOAPBugEnabled": false,
  "Source": {
    "Collection": "https://Org1.visualstudio.com/",
    "Project": "Project 1",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "PersonalAccessToken": "PAT",
    "LanguageMaps": {
      "AreaPath": "Project 1",
      "IterationPath": "Project 1"
    }
  },
  "Target": {
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/Org2",
    "Project": "Project 2",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "PersonalAccessToken": "PAT2",
    "LanguageMaps": {
      "AreaPath": "Project 2",
      "IterationPath": "Project 2"
    }
  },
    "FieldMaps": [],
  "WorkItemTypeDefinition": {
    "sourceWorkItemTypeName": "targetWorkItemTypeName"
  },
  "GitRepoMapping": null,
  "Processors": [
    {
      "ObjectType": "VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.Configuration.Processing.NodeStructuresMigrationConfig",
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "Enabled": true,
      "BasePaths": []
    },
    {
      "ObjectType": "VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.Configuration.Processing.WorkItemMigrationConfig",
      "ReplayRevisions": true,
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
      "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
      "BuildFieldTable": false,
      "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
      "QueryBit": "AND  [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] = '' AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan')",
      "OrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
      "Enabled": false,
      "LinkMigration": true,
      "AttachmentMigration": true,
      "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
      "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
      "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
      "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
      "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should open an issue on the project's GitHub page if you're having an issue with it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-devops-migration-tools